# How to find spectrum of a convolution operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Say $k$ be s.t. $\hat{k}$ is a bounded function on an LCA group $G$ and $Tf=f*k$. Then $T$ is bounded on $L^2(G)$. Is there anything I can say about $\sigma(T)$?  (except the properties that follow from $T$ being bounded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually convolution with $k$ defines a bounded operator on $L^2(G)$ if and only if $\hat k$ is bounded. In this case the spectrum is exactly the essential range of $\hat k$.

In fact if $m$ is any bounded measurable function on $\hat G$ then $m$ defines a bounded operator on $L^2(G)$ by $$\widehat{Tf}=m\hat f,$$whether or not there exists $k$ with $m=\hat k$. And the spectrum is the essential range of $m$; this is clear from the definitions if you note that $1/(m-\lambda)$ is essentially bounded if and only if $\lambda$ is not in the essential range of $m$.

Comment: Thank you, i edited my question, that is what I meant.

Comment: Why is it exactly the (ess.) range? Is it also the range if the FT of f is not bounded?

Comment: What about the case of m unbounded?

Comment: You should do _some_ of this yourself. If $m$ is not essentially bounded it's easy to see it does not define a bounded multiplication operator... you need that fact to verify what I said about the spectrum